# render the param-value of the web.xml in the initpage.jps file

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to render the para-value by using the configuration in the web.xml file in the WEB-INF directory but I am getting just `The default user from the servlet config is:`rendered (without the parm value of the web.xml file). Can someone explain me where my error is?

**initpage.jps**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
The default user from the servlet config is:
<%getServletConfig().getInitParameter("defaultUser");%>

</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>SimpleServletProject</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>InitJSP</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/initpage.jsp</jsp-file>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>defaultUser</param-name>
        <param-value>Default User Name</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>InitJSP</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>initpage.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Servlet init-param can be read only once. Look here [how-to-retrieve-init-parameter-in-jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14973125/how-to-retrieve-init-parameter-in-jsp)

Comment: You are using a scriptlet. You need a JSP expression.   Try using  <%=getServletConfig().getInitParameter("defaultUser")%>

Comment: @rickz: I tried your code but I am getting `null` at the end for your line.

Comment: I think it should work. In fact all these:  <%=config.getInitParameter("defaultUser")%> or <%=getInitParameter("defaultUser")%> 
or ${pageContext.servletConfig.getInitParameter("defaultUser")}  should work. Did you restart Tomcat ?

Comment: @rickz: Yes I did but nothing changed. And I have even restarted Eclipse.

Comment: I don't know why it is not working.  Maybe try adding / in  <url-pattern>/initpage.jsp</url-pattern> in your web.xml file  and change some text in the JSP so that you know that you are using current page. Restart Tomcat again.