# @WebInitParam value is null in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a simple servlet using annotations, all I want to do is to set initial values using servlet initialization parameters.

**SimpleServlet.java**

```
@WebServlet(
        description = "A simple servlet", 
        urlPatterns = { 
                "/SimpleServlet"
        }, loadOnStartup=1, initParams = {
                @WebInitParam(name="maximum", value="1000")
        })
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) {
        System.out.println(config.getInitParameter("maximum"));
    }
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.doPost(request, response);
    }
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
    pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<%
   out.print(config.getInitParameter("maximum"));
%>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Simple Servlet</display-name>
</web-app>
```

The init method prints 1000 which is correct. But the index.jsp prints null.
Can you tell me what's wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0):

The `@WebInitParam` will init a param for this servlet. So when you access to this servlet you have the param value but when you directly access to your jsp the value is `null`.
So you should access your jsp page through your servlet by hitting the url `/SimpleServlet`. This will help you:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }
```

Comment: Where can I configure this so that it comes to doGet method first? Because when I am running the project, it directly goes to index.jsp

Comment: You can set it in web xml like this:  <welcome-file-list><welcome-file>SimpleServlet<welcome-file><welcome-file-list>

Comment: @sunny93 did you tried to access via /SimpleServlet directly from the browser?

Comment: @sunny93 I think you need <contex-param> more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/14973367/4431053